# how to input value in this function?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, unity-game-engine, amazon-dynamodb

i want to input some data in aws QueryAsync fucntion but it doesn't work

how can i do that?

```
List<int> mNum = new List<int>();

mNum.Add(1);
mNum.Add(2);
mNum.Add(3);

client1.QueryAsync(request, (queryResult) =>
{
    if(queryResult.Exception != null)
    {
        print(queryResult.Exception.ToString());
        return;
    }

    foreach(var i in queryResult.Response.Items){ ... }

    mNum.Add(4);
});

for(int i = 0; i < mNum.Count; i++) print (mNum[i]); // count -> 3
```

[image]

Comment: Please don't post code nor errors as scrennshots, but use properly formatted code blocks.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is your code outside of the lambda expression is executed **immediately** before the query has finished so your line

```
mNum.Add(4);
```

is executed asynchronous long after the `for` loop was already executed and printed out the only `3` elements that existed at that moment.

You would rather have to wait for the callback and do it within the lambda like e.g.

```
List<int> mNum = new List<int>();

mNum.Add(1);
mNum.Add(2);
mNum.Add(3);

client1.QueryAsync(request, (queryResult) =>
{
    if(queryResult.Exception != null)
    {
        print(queryResult.Exception.ToString());
        return;
    }

    foreach(var i in queryResult.Response.Items){ ... }

    mNum.Add(4);

    foreach(var num in mNum)
    {
        print (num);
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks! it was good teaching for me :)